# Conditionally add attribute in angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to use the $scope to set if an attribute should be used or not in angular. Here is my scope:

```
fields:
    [
        {
            label: 'First Name',
            name: 'firstname',
            key: 'entry.326845034',
            type: 'text',
            required: true
        }
    ]
```

it's the required attribute I want to set. I'm imagining something like `{{if fields.required == true | required}}`, but I can''t find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Are you wanting to set required on a form element like this?

```
<input required>
```

If so you can use

```
<input ng-required="fields.required">
```

and the true/false state of the variable will end up applying or removing the required attribute on the input.

Answer (score 0):

By using `"ng-attr"` you can add attributes dynamically to your HTML ,If you have `angular 1.14` or later.

I have a table with two columns (ROLL NO & STUDENT NAME), I have to add a attribute(st-sort-default) to "STUDENT NAME" column to indicate users that table has been sorted by the same column.

I have used ng-attr property

`ng-attr-(attribute name required)="condition"`

If the condition is true it will add the attribute name you specified

e.g:-

**(--Controller--)**

```
$scope.headers= [{key:'id',title:'ROLL NO'},{key:'name',title:'STUDENT NAME'}]
```

**(--html--)**

```
<th ng-repeat="col in headers" ng-attr-st-sort-default="{{col.key ==='name'}}"> {{col.title}} 
</th>
```